# Add class to Button if element contains specific text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the class of a button to disabled if the text contains ACTIVE in another element. For some reason it's not working. I've gone over a few variations, but can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isactive = document.getElementById('userStatus');
    if (isactive.text() == "ACTIVE") {
        $("#addactionbutton").addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<td id="userStatus">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UserStatus)</td>

<td>
                    <button id="addactionbutton" type="button" class="addactionbutton btn btn-outline-primary" orguid="@item.Uid" title="Add User to Organization" orgname="@item.Name" isipaas="@item.IsIpassOrg.ToString()" userid="@item.UserId" orgid="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="removeactionbutton btn btn-outline-danger" userid="@item.UserId" title="Remove User from Organization" orgid="@item.Id" orguid="@item.Uid" isipaas="@item.IsIpassOrg"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                    <button id="unlockUser" type="button" class="unlockactionbutton btn btn-outline-primary" orguid="@item.Uid" title="Unlock Account" orgname="@item.Name" isipaas="@item.IsIpassOrg.ToString()" userid="@item.UserId" orgid="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i></button>
                </td>
```

Comment: `isactive` contains an Element object, not a jQuery object, so `text()` will be raising an error

Comment: Also, remove the `#`.  It's not needed with `getElementById()`

Comment: You're mixing javascript DOM elements and jquery objects.  Pick one and stick with it, eg in jquery `if ($(#userStatus).text()=="ACTIVE")`

Comment: post your html code

Answer (score 0):

Please try below mention code for check active string.

```
if($("#userStatus").html().indexOf('ACTIVE') == -1){
 $("#addactionbutton").addClass('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Ok, then you need to use like $("#userStatus").html().indexOf('ACTIVE') == -1

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly you're mixing up plain JS methods with jQuery. `isactive` will contain a Element object, not a jQuery object, so calling `text()` on that will be giving you an error. Secondly `getElementById()` does not need the `#` prefix on the argument you provide.

You can solve both issues by using jQuery itself to select the `#userStatus` element, like this:

```js
var $isActive = $('#userStatus')
if ($isActive.text().trim() == "ACTIVE") {
  $("#addactionbutton").addClass('disabled');
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userStatus">ACTIVE</div>
<button id="addactionbutton">Add action</button>
```

Alternatively if you'd like to stick with plain JS only:

```js
var isActive = document.querySelector('#userStatus');
if (isActive.innerText.trim() === 'ACTIVE') {
  document.querySelector('#addactionbutton').classList.add('disabled');
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userStatus">ACTIVE</div>
<button id="addactionbutton">Add action</button>
```

One final thing to note is that adding a `disabled` class to the element still allows it to be clicked. If you do not want that functionality, set the `disabled`  property to `true` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#userStatus').text().trim() == "ACTIVE") {
    $("#addactionbutton").addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>I am sample dom</p>
  <p id="userStatus">ACTIVE</p>
  <button id="addactionbutton">I am Button</button>
</div>
```